# How to add 'is-invalid' class on choices.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, choices.js

I am currently using validate.js to validate my form and choices.min.js as a substitute instead of using select in order for me to have a proper search bar on select. I am currently testing the choices.min.js my problem is the error message as well as the error class which is is-invalid is not adding or displaying. Kindly refer to this screenshot:

[image]

Here is my the html code:

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
<div class="choices" data-type="select-one" tabindex="0" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<div class="choices__inner">
<select class="form-control choices__input" data-trigger="" name="choices_single_default" id="choices_single_default" hidden="" tabindex="-1" data-choice="active">
    <option value="" data-custom-properties="[object Object]">--</option>
</select>
  <div class="choices__list choices__list--single">
    <div class="choices__item choices__placeholder choices__item--selectable" data-item="" data-id="1" data-value="" data-custom-properties="[object Object]" aria-selected="true">--</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="choices__list choices__list--dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  <div class="choices__list" role="listbox">
    <div id="choices--choices_single_default-item-choice-1" class="choices__item choices__item--choice is-selected choices__placeholder choices__item--selectable is-highlighted" role="option" data-choice="" data-id="1" data-value="" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="" aria-selected="true">--</div>
    <div id="choices--choices_single_default-item-choice-2" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable" role="option" data-choice="" data-id="2" data-value="Choice 1" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="">Choice 1</div>
    <div id="choices--choices_single_default-item-choice-3" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable" role="option" data-choice="" data-id="3" data-value="Choice 2" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="">Choice 2</div>
    <div id="choices--choices_single_default-item-choice-4" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable" role="option" data-choice="" data-id="4" data-value="Choice 3" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="">Choice 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
$('#signin-form').validate({
rules: {
  email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
  },
  choices_single_default: {
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    required: true
  }
},
messages: {
  email: {
    required: 'Please enter your email address',
    email: 'Please enter a valid email address'
  },
  choices_single_default: {
    required: 'Please enter your choice'
  },
  password: {
    required: 'Please enter your password'
  }
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent());
  } else if (element.hasClass('choices__input')) {
      error.insertAfter(element.siblings('.choices__list--dropdown'));
  } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
  }
},
highlight: function(element) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('choices__input')) {
        $(element).siblings('.choices__list--dropdown').addClass('is-invalid');
    } else {
        $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    }
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('choices__input')) {
        $(element).siblings('.choices__list--dropdown').removeClass('is-invalid');
    } else {
        $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
  // ajax code

  return false;
}
});
```

I have tried to use chat GPT to fix my problem but to no avail. I tried to read the documentation still not working.

Comment: Instead of using Chat GPT, how about searching SO under the jQuery Validate tag for something similar?  The solution would be a lot like using Select 2, or any other plugin that replaces the `select` element.

Comment: @Sparky I checked there were limitations with choices.js that is why I opted for select2 instead

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in one of your post above "I checked there were limitations with choices.js that is why I opted for select2 instead". Because you did not delete your post, I will still answer your question if others are still looking for an answer.

You can use the choices instance to add a class to `.containerInner.element`.
In this example we add our own css class called `.is-invalid`.

You can of course also use the function below to display the message when no option has been selected.

We also use the choices `passedElement.element.addEventListener` so that if the user does select an option, we can remove the `is_invalid` class.

**Example:**

```js
const mychoices = new Choices(document.querySelector('#mychoices'));
mychoices.passedElement.element.addEventListener('change', function() {
  checkInputfield(mychoices);
});

$(document).on('click', '.submit_data', function() {
  checkInputfield(mychoices);
});

function checkInputfield(my_choices) {
  let inner_element = my_choices.containerInner.element;
  if (my_choices.getValue(true)) {
    inner_element.classList.remove('is-invalid');
  } else {
    inner_element.classList.add('is-invalid');
  }
}
```

```css
.is-invalid {
  border: 1px solid #dc3545 !important;
}

.is-invalid::after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f06a";
  color: #dc3545;
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://choices-js.github.io/Choices/assets/styles/choices.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/choices.js/9.1.0/choices.min.js"></script>

<div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-6">
    <label for="mychoices" class="form-label">Select an option</label>
    <select id="mychoices" class="form-control choices-single">
      <option value="" hidden>Make a choice...</option>
      <option value="1">Option A</option>
      <option value="2">Option B</option>
      <option value="3">Option C</option>
      <option value="4">Option D</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="submit_data btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```